# Element bg image not showing

Tags: css, html, background-image

If i give a div a bg image like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<style>

#image {
background-image:url(Images/1.jpg);
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
z-index:9999;
}

</style>
</head> 
<body style="background-color:#FFF;" >

  <div id="image"> </div>

</body></html>
```

Then nothing shows. What am i doing wrong? My image is linked correctly, and unless im supposed to put something in the div this should be working.

Comment: It doesn't have a width or a height

Comment: Just tried that, still nothing.

Comment: your background image has two close parenthesis'

Comment: add `&nbsp;` to your div so that it has content

Comment: I copied your markup exactly and pasted it into a blank html file.  I changed the image to a 100x100 image.  Everything is showing up in Chrome 20/IE 8/Firefox 10.

Answer (score 1):

your div is empty and no dimension was set. The background image alone cannot expand the element until it's visible, that's why you need to specify `width` and `height`

if this still doesn't work

1. Check for syntax errors on css file
2. Check image permission (be sure it's `644` or greater)

Comment: add `&nbsp;` to your div so that it has content

Comment: Why does everyone keep telling me to do what ive already done, this just isnt working

Comment: @user1361747 probably you should post an example fiddle with the image you're trying to use. maybe you've no enough permission for image file

Comment: Its just a jpg and im running as admin but why would that matter as the entire web would be just text if i couldnt see images. God forget it html is such a worthless language to learn it only works half the time on a tenth of the browsers. They cant even offer a standard way for pages to load so now i gotta spend hours figuring out what to put in the head of the document just to get it to render. If real programs were written in html then only 9% of planes would make it to their destination.

Answer (score 0):

The height defaults to the height of the content.  Since there is no content, the height is 0.  The width is usually auto, but when absolutely positioned, width has becomes 0 as well.

So just add a width and height to `#myimage`

example:

```
#myimage {
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:9999;
    /*new*/
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NuCzS/

Comment: already tried that, doesnt work. Updated with complete markup for reference, plz check again.

Comment: can you recreate your example in a jsFiddle?

Comment: sounds like a syntax error.  They can be frustrating and small. but if you can see the correct output in the jsFiddle, then you might have missed a close tag or a spelling error or something in your local files.